# Unity windows build crashing due to Access violation error

Tags: unity, crash

I have unity player build for windows working fine on my pc while my client facing a crash with access violation log. Usually access violation occur(I experienced)

1. Low disk space
2. Heavy project
3. 32 or 64 bit architecture problem

but in this case there nothing like that it is a small project even working fine on low end PC.
Here is the crash log

> Unity Player [version: Unity 5.6.2f1_a2913c821e27]
>
> Player-08.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)   in module
>   Player-08.exe at 0033:cd0816c7.
>
> Error occurred at 2019-01-07_132626. D:\DD
>   \MM\03_Medien\Player\Ab\UW\Player-08.exe,
>   run by KJ. 30% memory in use. 8073 MB physical memory [5577 MB free].
>   11145 MB paging file [7898 MB free]. 134217728 MB user address space
>   [134213247 MB free]. Read from location 0000000e caused an access
>   violation.
>
> Context: RDI:    0x00005853  RSI: 0x00001003  RAX:   0x00000000 RBX:
>   0x0091ee20  RCX: 0x0000000e  RDX:   0x00000000 RIP:    0xcd0816c7 
>   RBP: 0x00000001  SegCs: 0x00000033 EFlags: 0x00010293  RSP: 0x0091ebf0
>   SegSs: 0x0000002b R8:    0x00000010  R9: 0x00000001  R10:   0xcd827f88
>   R11:    0x00000000  R12: 0x00000010  R13:   0x00000000 R14:
>   0x0638ae00  R15: 0x0091ed80
>
> Bytes at CS:EIP: 0f b7 31 33 ff 48 8d 59 02 44 8d 7f 08 eb 07 0f
>
> Stack: 0x0091ebf0: 06880031 00000000 8109a088 00007ffc
>   1............... 0x0091ec00: 00000000 00000000 0091ece8 00000000 ................ 0x0091ec10: 0091ed80 00000000 0638ae00 00000000
>   ..........8..... 0x0091ec20: 06872978 00000000 06842048 00000000
>   x)......H ...... 0x0091ec30: 00005853 00000000 00001003 00000000
>   SX.............. 0x0091ec40: 0091ecd9 00000000 ccfec664 00007ff7
>   ........d....... 0x0091ec50: 0000000e 00000000 06842048 00000000
>   ........H ...... 0x0091ec60: 0091ee20 00000000 0091ece8 00000000 
>   ............... 0x0091ec70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ec80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ec90: 0091eca8 00000000 7d16ca21 00007ffc
>   ........!..}.... 0x0091eca0: 06896590 00000000 0682d500 00000000
>   .e.............. 0x0091ecb0: 06891440 00000000 06787960 00000000
>   @.......`yx..... 0x0091ecc0: 02a8c060 00000000 00000024 00000000`
>   .......$....... 0x0091ecd0: 7d160000 00007ffc 00000024 00000000
>   ...}....$....... 0x0091ece0: 00000042 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   B............... 0x0091ecf0: 0688ed98 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ed00: 00000001 00000000 00000005 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ed10: 0638ae70 00000000 03db10d8 00000000
>   p.8............. 0x0091ed20: 0091f118 00000000 03db1060 00000000
>   ........`....... 0x0091ed30: 0091f190 00000000 ccfec7ca 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091ed40: 00000000 00000000 cd828020 00007ff7
>   ........ ....... 0x0091ed50: 06868d30 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   0............... 0x0091ed60: 00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 ................ 0x0091ed70: 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ed80: 00000000 00000000 7d052690 00007ffc
>   .........&.}.... 0x0091ed90: 00000000 00000000 00b63e28 00000000
>   ........(>...... 0x0091eda0: 00b63da0 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   .=.............. 0x0091edb0: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091edc0: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091edd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ede0: 00000000 00000000 31910000 00007ffc
>   ...........1.... 0x0091edf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee00: 00000001 00000007 00000001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee20: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020
>   N.V.I.D.I.A. .G. 0x0091ee30: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020
>   e.F.o.r.c.e. .9. 0x0091ee40: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000
>   4.0.M.X......... 0x0091ee50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................ 0x0091ee60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ee90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eea0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eeb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eec0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eed0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eef0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ef00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ef10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ef20: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2
>   ....M...C....... 0x0091ef30: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ..>~............ 0x0091ef40: fc431000 00000000 0000bf9e 00000000
>   ..C............. 0x0091ef50: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020
>   N.V.I.D.I.A. .G. 0x0091ef60: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020
>   e.F.o.r.c.e. .9. 0x0091ef70: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000
>   4.0.M.X......... 0x0091ef80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................ 0x0091ef90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091efa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091efb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091efc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091efd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091efe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091eff0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f010: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f030: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f050: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2
>   ....M...C....... 0x0091f060: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ..>~............ 0x0091f070: fc431000 00000000 0000bf9e 00000000
>   ..C............. 0x0091f080: 00000008 00000000 cc963a7b 00007ff7
>   ........{:...... 0x0091f090: 03db1060 00000000 03db1060 00000000`
>   .......`....... 0x0091f0a0: 00000008 00000000 03db10d8 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f0b0: 0091f2b0 00000000 00000400 00007ffc
>   ................ 0x0091f0c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f0d0: 00000000 00007ff7 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f0e0: 00000000 00000000 00b63da0 00000000
>   .........=...... 0x0091f0f0: 00b63da0 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   .=.............. 0x0091f100: 0638a698 00000000 00b63da0 00000000
>   ..8......=...... 0x0091f110: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f130: 00000000 00000000 00000042 00007ffc
>   ........B....... 0x0091f140: 02a960b0 00000000 0000001a 00000000
>   .`.............. 0x0091f150: 00460065 0072006f 0000001a 00000000
>   e.F.o.r......... 0x0091f160: 00000042 0058004d 00000000 00000000
>   B...M.X......... 0x0091f170: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f180: 0056004e 00440049 00410049 00470020
>   N.V.I.D.I.A. .G. 0x0091f190: 00460065 0072006f 00650063 00390020
>   e.F.o.r.c.e. .9. 0x0091f1a0: 00300034 0058004d 00000000 00000000
>   4.0.M.X......... 0x0091f1b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................ 0x0091f1c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f1d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f1e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f1f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f200: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f210: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f220: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f230: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f240: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f250: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f260: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f270: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f280: 000010de 0000134d 138e1043 000000a2
>   ....M...C....... 0x0091f290: 7e3e0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ..>~............ 0x0091f2a0: fc431000 00000000 0000bf9e 00000000
>   ..C............. 0x0091f2b0: 4449564e 47204149 726f4665 39206563
>   NVIDIA GeForce 9 0x0091f2c0: 584d3034 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   40MX............ 0x0091f2d0: 00000000 00000000 7cd95b90 00007ffc
>   .........[.|.... 0x0091f2e0: 0091f371 00000000 7cd95a38 00007ffc
>   q.......8Z.|.... 0x0091f2f0: 7cd958e0 00007ffc 00000000 00000000
>   .X.|............ 0x0091f300: 000000c4 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f310: 02a7f230 00000000 00000004 00000000
>   0............... 0x0091f320: 00000007 00007ffc 00000000 00000000 ................ 0x0091f330: 037ae8b0 00000000 cd02d369 00007ff7
>   ..z.....i....... 0x0091f340: cda04340 00007ff7 cdab2d50 00007ff7
>   @C......P-...... 0x0091f350: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f360: 037ae8b0 00000000 cd02d79d 00007ff7
>   ..z............. 0x0091f370: 00000010 00000000 0378d050 00000000
>   ........P.x..... 0x0091f380: 00000001 00000000 00b63da0 00000000
>   .........=...... 0x0091f390: 00000010 00000000 cc747241 00007ff7
>   ........Art..... 0x0091f3a0: 00000010 00000000 cdb098a0 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f3b0: 0091f4a8 00000000 7cd9593c 00007ffc
>   ....................... 0x0091f710: 43000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ...C............ 0x0091f720: cd72c26c 00007ff7 cce8bd60 00007ff7
>   l.r.....`....... 0x0091f730: 037ae690 00000000 cc9ad86e 00007ff7
>   ..z.....n....... 0x0091f740: 00000000 00000000 00000017 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f750: 00000000 00000000 cd72c26c 00007ff7
>   ........l.r..... 0x0091f760: 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f770: 00000000 00000000 cc9bcaa6 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f780: 03fa2e60 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   `............... 0x0091f790: 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f7a0: 00800000 00000000 00000065 00007ff7
>   ........e....... 0x0091f7b0: 037adbe0 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   ..z............. 0x0091f7c0: 00000000 00000000 cc9318ec 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f7d0: 00000000 00000000 cc670000 00007ff7
>   ..........g..... 0x0091f7e0: 00000000 00000000 03f9bd30 00000000
>   ........0....... 0x0091f7f0: 00000000 00000000 cc93403c 00007ff7
>   ........<@...... 0x0091f800: cda9fe01 00007ff7 0091f859 00000000
>   ........Y....... 0x0091f810: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f820: cda280e0 00007ff7 cd07d81e 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f830: 00000000 00000000 cd7da718 00007ff7
>   ..........}..... 0x0091f840: 00000000 00000000 63726f66 66672d65
>   ........force-gf 0x0091f850: 6f6a2d78 00007362 0000000e 00000000
>   x-jobs.......... 0x0091f860: 00000042 00007ff7 0091f8c8 00000000
>   B............... 0x0091f870: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f880: 00000000 00000000 ccb11dea 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f890: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f8a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f8b0: 0091f960 00000000 cce9bf4b 00007ff7`
>   .......K....... 0x0091f8c0: cd7da718 00007ff7 00000000 00000000
>   ..}............. 0x0091f8d0: 00000000 00000000 02a6f9e0 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f8e0: 00000000 00000000 cce99bee 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091f8f0: 0000776f 00000000 0000000a 00000000
>   ow.............. 0x0091f900: 00000042 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   B............... 0x0091f910: 00000050 0000002b cc6d97c0 00007ff7
>   P...+.....m..... 0x0091f920: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f930: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f940: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f950: 00000000 00000000 02a6f9e0 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f960: 0091fa70 00000000 cc6de97a 00007ff7
>   p.......z.m..... 0x0091f970: 00cf0000 00000000 00000140 00000000
>   ........@....... 0x0091f980: 000000f0 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f990: 00000000 00000000 cc747268 00007ff7
>   ........hrt..... 0x0091f9a0: cd728370 00007ff7 cd72bac0 00007ff7
>   p.r.......r..... 0x0091f9b0: 00000000 00000000 ffebffff 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091f9c0: 0091fa4c 00000000 cd6f7568 00007ff7
>   L.......huo..... 0x0091f9d0: 026ea310 00000000 cd02d79d 00007ff7
>   ..n............. 0x0091f9e0: 00000000 00000000 00637465 00646567
>   ........etc.ged. 0x0091f9f0: cda28f10 00007ff7 00000003 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fa00: 00000042 00000000 02a6f990 00000000
>   B............... 0x0091fa10: 02a6f9e0 00000000 02a6f9e0 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fa20: 00000000 00000000 026ea3e0 00000000
>   ..........n..... 0x0091fa30: 026ea3e0 00000000 02a67af0 00000000
>   ..n......z...... 0x0091fa40: 0000005d 00000000 00000408 00000016
>   ]............... 0x0091fa50: 0000005d 00000000 00000042 00007ffc
>   ].......B....... 0x0091fa60: 026ea450 00000000 026ea3e0 00000000
>   P.n.......n..... 0x0091fa70: 02a83b20 00000000 00000066 00000000 
>   ;......f....... 0x0091fa80: 0091faf0 00000000 00000066 00000000
>   ........f....... 0x0091fa90: 00000042 000000b2 02a67bb0 00000000
>   B........{...... 0x0091faa0: 00000058 00000000 cd086416 00007ff7
>   X........d...... 0x0091fab0: 00000058 00000000 00000042 00000000
>   X.......B....... 0x0091fac0: 02a83b90 00000000 00000060 00000000
>   .;......`....... 0x0091fad0: 00000004 00000000 00000060 00000000
>   ........`....... 0x0091fae0: 00000042 00000000 02a83d50 00000000
>   B.......P=...... 0x0091faf0: 00000067 00000000 cd07de1a 00007ff7
>   g............... 0x0091fb00: 00000067 00000000 00000042 00007ff7
>   g.......B....... 0x0091fb10: 0000000f 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fb20: 00000000 00000000 cd07debe 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091fb30: 00000022 00000000 02a83ab0 00000000
>   "........:...... 0x0091fb40: 00000061 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   a............... 0x0091fb50: 00000061 00000000 00000042 00007ff7
>   a.......B....... 0x0091fb60: cda28f10 00007ff7 02841f20 00000000
>   ........ ....... 0x0091fb70: 02840840 00000000 cd72ba01 00007ff7
>   @.........r..... 0x0091fb80: 00000000 00000000 cd09019a 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091fb90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fba0: 00000000 00000000 cc670000 00007ff7
>   ..........g..... 0x0091fbb0: 00000000 00000000 cd081dcc 00007ff7
>   ................ 0x0091fbc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fbd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fbe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fbf0: 00000068 00000000 00b22a0e 00000000
>   h........*...... 0x0091fc00: 00b229ee 00000000 00b2293e 00000000
>   .)......>)...... 0x0091fc10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000401
>   ................ 0x0091fc30: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc40: 00000000 00000000 00010001 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc60: 00000000 00000000 81e33034 00007ffc
>   ........40...... 0x0091fc70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fc90: 00000000 00000000 82103691 00007ffc
>   .........6...... 0x0091fca0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fcb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fcc0: 00000000 00000000 7f04bb60 00007ffc
>   ........`....... 0x0091fcd0: 0091dcd0 00000000 0091dcd0 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fce0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fcf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fd90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fda0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fdb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fdc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fdd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fde0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fdf0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fe90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fea0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091feb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fec0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fed0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fef0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff10: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff30: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff50: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff70: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ff90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ffa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ffb0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ffc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ffd0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091ffe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................ 0x0091fff0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   ................
>
> == [end of error.log] ==

But at this case my client getting this crash log:

while output log is:

```
Initialize engine version: 5.6.2f1 (a2913c821e27)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath:.....so on long file
```

As the error is not producing on my system, i can't say anything about it. My client running win10.

Comment: I found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsMR/comments/9jtj79/help_with_access_violation_error/e9g5kel/) with someone who has issues with all Unity games. Apparently Citrix Receiver was causing the issue. So it's possible it's some program that's reserving the memory which Unity wanna use.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using Unity 5.6.1 anymore. It is considered outdated in 2019. Unity 2018.1 is the latest stable version to use at the time of writing. If the problem persists, contact Unity.

Comment: @HappyGuyDK Yeah, You may be right my initial research also found that Citrix Application is the cause.